# Help with apt-get on non-internet connected device

Tags: package-management, angstrom, opkg

I have a Linux based OS running on an embedded piece of hardware. According to the manufacturer of this device, it's based on the Ångström distribution. This device cannot be connected to the internet, however I need to install the ntp package on it so I can assign it to ntp to a local server. I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 that I can get the ntp package with. I can also connect the laptop to that device. Is there a way I can 'host' (forgive me if this is the wrong word) that package on my laptop so the embedded device can get the package from there, rather than getting it from the internet.

Comment: If you need to install several packages etc. you could (perhaps) make a local repository. Find the correct one to `wget` (or the like) here: http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/ , set up a server on your laptop and configure `/etc/opkg.conf` on the device to use the local server. Then `okpg update` and install as normal.

Answer (score 2):

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) says, Ångström uses opkg for package management designed for embedded devices that resembled Debian's dpkg. So you can download your package, copy it on your device and run `opkg install <package_name>.ipkg`.